# Notifications on asp.net website

Tags: c#, jquery

I am NOT talking about Chrome / Firefox browser notifications.

I am looking for an engine which can "push" information to a session of a particular logged in user on any browser which can be shown within the system using a simple jquery toastr plugins.

The design till now i have in mind is as follows:

- when a user logs in save a dynamically generated session Id and user id and a expiry time
- during the back end transactions, if any user has to be notified about something, check in the data collected from above step if the user is logged in and get the session Id and generate the notification content.
- now, the engine has to "push" the generated content to that particular web browser instance and help is needed at this step on how to do it.

I don't want the client to pool the server at given frequency if there are any updates.

We have solutions for mobile apps but how to achieve the same for browser application

Thanks.

Comment: You can also read HTML5 post message to find some hints https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) right?

Some Google results:

- http://moderngeekdad.com/create-a-push-notification-system-with-signalr-and-toastr/
- http://mahedee.net/a-signalr-application-for-real-time-notification-using-angularjs-and-toastr/

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools which you can use

1. [Pusher](https://pusher.com/)
2. [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)

You can easily manage push notifications with this.